# Unclear result in characterization of subharmonic functions.

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

Let $\Omega$ be a region in $\mathbb{C}$ and let $\phi:\Omega \to [-\infty,+\infty)$ be an upper semicontinuous function. TFAE: \
i)$\phi$ is subharmonic in $\Omega$,

ii) for any disc $\Delta_{z_0,r} \subset \subset \Omega$ we have 
$$ \phi(x_0) \leq (2\pi r)^{-1} \int_{\partial \Delta_{z_0,r}} \phi \; ds, $$ where ds is the element of arc,

iii) For any $\Delta_{z_0,r} \subset \subset \Omega$ we have
$$ \phi(x_0) \leq (-2i\pi r^2)^{-1} \int_{ \Delta_{z_0,r}} \phi \; d\tau \wedge d\overline{\tau} $$

This is the seemingly awkward statement of a common characterization theorem one finds for subharmonic functions, from which I have omitted another equivalent condition because it wasn't relevant. I'm stuck in trying to prove that ii) implies iii). Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polar coordinates. For $0 < \rho \leqslant r$, we have

$$2\pi\rho \phi(z_0) \leqslant \int_{0}^{2\pi} \phi\left(z_0 + \rho e^{i\vartheta}\right)\,\rho\,d\vartheta,$$

by ii), and integrating that inequality from $0$ to $r$, we obtain

$$\begin{align}
\pi r^2\phi(z_0) &= \int_0^r 2\pi \rho \phi(z_0)\,d\rho\\
&\leqslant \int_0^r \int_0^{2\pi} \phi\left(z_0 + \rho e^{i\vartheta}\right)\rho\,d\vartheta\,d\rho\\
&= \iint_{\Delta_{z_0\,r}} \phi(x+iy)\,dx\wedge dy\\
&= \frac{i}{2} \iint_{\Delta_{z_0\,r}} \phi(\tau) d\tau\wedge d\overline{\tau}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Hi, the tricky passage is the last one, I thought $dx \wedge dy = \frac{1}{2i} d\tau \wedge d\overline{\tau}$

Comment: No, it's $d\tau\wedge d\overline{\tau} = (dx+i\,dy)\wedge (dx-i\,dy) = dx\wedge(-i\,dy) + (i\,dy)\wedge dx = -2i\,dx\wedge dy$.